# How to read json object sent over post request and save/append to in memory json object- Node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to read the sent request and save in the following JSON object. `console.log` does not even log the data to console. I tried `JSON.Parse()`, didn't work.

```
var express = require('express'); 
bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
pp.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 
app.post('/addteacher', function(request,response){ 
  console.log(request.body); 
}); 
//var inMemory = { teacher: { 1: { id: 1, name: 'name example 1', age: 23, job: 'example job'`, co-workers: [] }, } };
```

Comment: How are you calling the `/addteacher` endpoint?

Comment: I think @MariaInesParnisari has the hint here: make sure you're setting the Content-Type header to application/json in whatever method you're using to call the /addteacher endpoint...

Comment: yes, thank you , "application/json" was the issue, I can read the request.body. I tried to find how to append the incoming json object to in memory Json object.